# How to remove methods of reference class and the objects in R

Tags: python, r, rpy2

This is going to be a very long question. So, pardon me

I have the following scenario, I guess it will be better to give a pseudo code to explain things better

A python file say **test.py**

```
def test(i):
    from rpy2.robjects import r
    r.source('r_file.R')
    r.call_function(with some arguments)

    #Some Operations
    del r
```

File: **r_file.R**

```
rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))

#some global variables
#some reference class

#creating an object of reference class
call_function = function(some arguments)
{
    Do some processing
    call few methods on a reference class

    call some more methods and do some operations

    rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))
    gc()

    return(0)

}
```

The call to the the function test in python happens for some values of 'i' i.e the function gets called for some values of i which is always greater than 1 i.e the function gets invoked multiple times from **main**. Hence, we source the R file more than once. I wanted a new R interpreter every time I invoke the python function. Therefore, I import r every time the function is called and also delete the rpy2 object.

Within the r function "call_function", I invoke some methods, which in turn creates reference class objects.

Within the R code, I use rm in the beginning of the code and also when the function some_function exits.

Given this background, the problem which I'm facing now is that the rm does not remove any of the reference class in the code and I keep getting some warning like this

```
In .removePreviousCoerce(class1, class2, where, prevIs) :
  methods currently exist for coercing from "Rev_R5" to "envRefClass"; they will be replaced
```

Here, Rev_R5 is a reference class. I do not want this to happen, is there a way to remove all the **methods**, **objects** related to the reference classes using rm ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your creating a fresh R session for each invocation - doing that will be the easiest fix.

Comment: Thats what I exactly want. How to create a fresh R session for each invocation using rpy2 ?

Answer (score 4):

Removing all objects from R's global environment does not mean that you are back to a freshly started R process (class and method definitions may remain, as you discovered it).

R functions such as `removeClass()`, `removeMethod()`, or `removeGeneric` could be considered but unless there are objective requirements to do so (like avoid the loading of large objects over and over again), creating R processes each time might just be the safest way to go (starting an R process is relatively fast).

Since it is not possible to terminate and restart an embedded R (limitation coming from R, not rpy2), so you'll have to start and stop Python processes embedding R.

One way to do so is to use the Python package `multiprocessing` (included in Python's standard library). An added bonus is that the processes can be run in parallel.

Simple examle using [Doug Hellmann's excellent tutorial](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html) as a base:

```
import multiprocessing

def R_worker(i):
    """worker function"""

    print('Worker %i started' % i)
    from rpy2.robjects import r
    r.source('r_file.R')
    r.call_function(with some arguments)

    #Some Operations
    del r
    return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for i in range(5):
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target = R_worker, args=(i,))
        jobs.append(p)
        p.start()
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the suggestion. This is indeed a very good solution. But, I have the constraint of not using multithreading or multiprocessing. Essentially, I need to create a fresh R session for every invocation. How to do that ?

Comment: One way or the other (sequential or parallel) you are going to have to use one process per fresh R session wanted.

Comment: I added a comment about R's `removeClass()` and friends, but that might be a less-used part of the R codebase and you might be up for surprises.